# Dot Product /w Neon Intrinsics

Tags: c++, optimization, floating-point, arm, neon

I'm trying to write an optimized dot product for an ARM A8 processor using Neon intrinsics but I'm having a little trouble. First of all, is there any library that already implements this? My code seems to work, but causes some quiet failures during run-time - my best guess is because there is a slight loss of precision compared to the unoptimized code. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I would be very grateful for any help or suggestions. Thanks in advance.

This particualar dot product is a 32 bit float * 32 bit float complex.

Here is the unoptimized code:

```
    double sum_re = 0.0;
    double sum_im = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++, src1++, src2++)
    {
            sum_re += *src1 * src2->re;
            sum_im += *src1 * src2->im;
    }
```

Here is my optimized version:

```
    float sum_re = 0.0;
    float sum_im = 0.0;

    float to_sum_re[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    float to_sum_im[4] = {0,0,0,0};

    float32x4_t tmp_sum_re, tmp_sum_im, source1;
    float32x4x2_t source2;
    tmp_sum_re = vld1q_f32(to_sum_re);
    tmp_sum_im = vld1q_f32(to_sum_im);

    int i = 0;

    while (i < (len & ~3)) {
            source1 = vld1q_f32(&src1[i]);
            source2 = vld2q_f32((const float32_t*)&src2[i]);

            tmp_sum_re = vmlaq_f32(tmp_sum_re, source1, source2.val[0]);
            tmp_sum_im = vmlaq_f32(tmp_sum_im, source1, source2.val[1]);

            i += 4;
    }
    if (len & ~3) {
            vst1q_f32(to_sum_re, tmp_sum_re);
            vst1q_f32(to_sum_im, tmp_sum_im);

            sum_re += to_sum_re[0] + to_sum_re[1] + to_sum_re[2] + to_sum_re[3];
            sum_im += to_sum_im[0] + to_sum_im[1] + to_sum_im[2] + to_sum_im[3];
    }

    while (i < len)
    {
            sum_re += src1[i] * src2[i].re;
            sum_im += src1[i] * src2[i].im;
            i++;
    }
```

Comment: Did you write the outputs and checked if they are different and by how much?

Comment: This may not be a representative example, but the first time the function is called: -  - - - WITH NEON: {re = 54.041008, im = 29.197485}   WITHOUT NEON: {re = 54.0410004, im = 29.1974678}

Comment: Ettus e110 (similar to a beagleboard) running Angstrom

Answer (score 5):

If you are using iOS, use vDSP_zrdotpr in the Accelerate framework. (vDSP_zrdotpr returns the dot product of a real vector with a complex vector. There are other variants, such as for real-to-real or complex-to-complex.)

Of course there is a loss of precision; your unoptimized code accumulates double-precision sums, while the NEON code accumulates single-precision sums.

Even without a precision change, the results would be expected to differ because doing floating-point operations in different orders produces different rounding errors. (This is true for integers too; if you calculate 7/3*5, you get 10, but 5*7/3 is 11.)

There are algorithms for doing floating-point arithmetic with reduced error. However, for doing a high-performance dot product, you are generally stuck with what you get.

One option would be to do the arithmetic with double-precision NEON instructions. This will not be as fast a single-precision NEON, of course, but it will be faster than scalar (non-NEON) code.

Comment: Two notes: Even though you accumulate double-precision sums in the scalar code, the multiplication is in single-precision, so the final errors are typical of that rather than what double-precision throughout would produce. And, while vDSP_zrdotpr can multiply by an interleaved complex vector (stride of two), I suspect it is not optimized for that case. You could file a bug report requesting it at bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that I did and currently in a commercial product.  Hopefully, it helps.  The only requirement is that the two multiplicands (src1, srcs->re) must be multiples of four.

```
float dotProduct4 (const float *a, const float *b, int n) {
float net1D=0.0f;
assert(n%4==0);     // required floats 'a' & 'b' to be multiple of 4
#ifdef __ARM_NEON__
asm volatile (
              "vmov.f32 q8, #0.0          \n\t" // zero out q8 register
              "1:                         \n\t"
              "subs %3, %3, #4            \n\t" // we load 4 floats into q0, and q2 register
              "vld1.f32 {d0,d1}, [%1]!    \n\t" // loads q0, update pointer *a
              "vld1.f32 {d4,d5}, [%2]!    \n\t" // loads q2, update pointer *b
              "vmla.f32 q8, q0, q2        \n\t" // store four partial sums in q8
              "bgt 1b                     \n\t"   // loops to label 1 until n==0
              "vpadd.f32 d0, d16, d17     \n\t"   // pairwise add 4 partial sums in q8, store in d0
              "vadd.f32 %0, s0, s1        \n\t"   // add 2 partial sums in d0, store result in return variable net1D
              : "=w"(net1D)                 // output
              : "r"(a), "r"(b), "r"(n)      // input
              : "q0", "q2", "q8");          // clobber list
#else
for (int k=0; k < n; k++) {
    net1D += a[k] * b[k];
}
#endif
return net1D;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for other implementations, there is the NEON OpenMAX DL implementation from ARM.
Linked to from http://www.arm.com/community/multimedia/standards-apis.php.

Downloading requires registration, and the format is RVCT assembler, but for looking at a set of examples of how to use NEON (including a dot product implementation), it's pretty good.